# I get an Error 404 in my Django App in app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, http-status-code-404

I have deployed successfully my Django app in App Engine (standard environment) but I get this message:

**Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server.**

In the dashboard there are no Application and server errors but there are two clients errors whose URI are: **/favicon.ico** and **/myapp/**

In the Logs Explorer I can find a 404 error before the app starts working and it ends with a 301.

Comment: Did you run `collectstatic` and set `STATIC_ROOT`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: Yes, I did both of them

Comment: Sorry for late reply. According to the docs you need to define handlers for staticfiles in your `app.yaml`, hope it helps
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/serving-static-files

I have not tried google app engine yet, but I had a similar problem on AWS, and I had to explicitly tell where static files are located in my `config` file

Comment: Hey @VíctorMoreno, to get best help, you'll need to describe if you are running on GAE Standard or GAE Flexible and the Python version. GAE for Py 2 and Py 3 are different.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your web server is functioning normally, the reason why you got a 404 error is because the resource that was requested doesn't exist.

Can you please follow the official documentation regarding:

[Running Django on the App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine)

You will have to perform the following steps :

1. Downloading and running the app
2. Running the app on your local computer
3. Deploying the app to the App Engine standard environment